# Access Json Object

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json object(jsencodedata) that is printed in Javascript like that:

```
document.write(jsencodedata);
```

It prints:

```
[{"user":"John","Pass":"abc123"},{"user":"John2","Pass":"abcdef"}]
```

My question is how to get only the first user or password or only the second one?
I'm new to this, so please excuse me for the stupid question?

Comment: `var arr = JSON.parse( jsencodedata );`, and then `arr[0]` to get the first object, and `arr[1]` to get the second object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (assuming jsencodeddata is a JSON string):

```
var users = JSON.parse(jsencodeddata);
console.log(users[0]); // the first user object
console.log(users[1]['Pass']); // second user's password
```

That will convert the JSON string into an actual array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
jsencodedata[0].user;  //returns "John"
jsencodedata[0].Pass;  //returns "abc123"
```

The array indices tell you what object to access [0] means you are accessing the first object and [1] means you are accessing the second object.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using [a browser with native JSON support](http://caniuse.com/json), then:

```
var arrData = JSON.parse(jsencodedata);
```

will parse the JSON string into an array, and then:

`arrData[0]` is the first user.
`arrData[0].user` is the first user's name.
`arrData[0].Pass` is the first user's password.

`arrData[1]` is the second user.
`arrData[1].user` is the second user's name.
`arrData[1].Pass` is the second user's password.